# Calculating the largest single gap from multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql

My table:

```
id  name    year
1   Carl    1923
2   Carl    1924
3   Carl    1927
4   Carl    1939
5   Carl    1990
6   Carl    1992
7   Carl    1993
8   Suki    1962
9   Suki    1972
10  Suki    2002
11  Suki    2003
```

I would like to calculate the **largest gap** between years for both Carl and Suki. So the result I'm expecting is:

```
Carl    51
Suki    30
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really want a `lag()` or `lead()` function.  Absent that, one method is correlated subqueries:

```
select name, max(year - prev_year) as max_diff
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.year
              from t t2
              where t2.name = t.name and t2.year < t.year
              order by year desc
              limit 1
             ) as prev_year
      from t
     ) t
group by name;
```

If you know that the `id`s have no gaps (at least within a name), you can use a more performant `join` query:

```
select t.name, max(t.year - tprev.year) as max_diff
from t join
     t tprev
     on t.year = tprev.year + 1 and t.name = tprev.name
group by t.name;
```

Comment: why not `select max(t2.year)`

Comment: @f.khantsis . . . That works as well, in the first subquery.

Comment: just as I though, it doesn't work. 'Subquery returns more than one row'. You gotta wrap it with `max`

Comment: @f.khantsis . . . Amusing.  There was supposed to be a `limit 1` in that.  That's what I meant by "as well".

Comment: Thanks - the correlated subqueries worked best for me.

Answer (score -1):

SORRY, I did realise later that this wasn't a PHP question.
May be it can help someone in the future
How about you do the following:

1. Retrieve $query_result through SQL
2. create variable $name="", $year=0, $diff=-1
3. Iterate through each $row and check
    
       `if $row['name'] is != $name
       if so then do $year=$row['year'] and $diff=0,
       else check if($diff<($row['year']-($year+$diff)))
            #update diff
            $diff=$row['year']-($year+$diff)
            $year=$row['year']`
4. For Printing you can either print previous values when $row['name'] is != $name
   or, save them in {key:value} JSON format and print in the end!

Comment: I have written this approach just for your help if you are implementing this using PHP
I forgot that it was just MySQL :P